# SwiftUI: disable interactions on transparent parts of ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, scrollview

Assuming I have a horizontal `ScrollView`, where the first item has a view  a lot taller than the rest. **Is there any way to limit the interaction to the visible elements** (black rectangles in the image below)?

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1) {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 70)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }
        ForEach((1...10), id: \.self) { _ in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
.background(.yellow)
```

[image]

I don't want to have the invisible area here blocking everything beneath that view, so everything in the red area should not scroll on the scrollview.

In my case, there’s a zoomable `ScrollView` in horizontal and vertical direction behind it and text all over it that can be tapped on (live text image view).

[image]

---

Here are my ideas, I was either not smart enough to properly implement them or it's simply not possible:

- `allowsHitTesting(false)` on `ScrollView` and enable on the child views: child views can't be enabled if parent is off
- `.contentShape(...)` on `ScrollView`: doesn't disable scrolling, also I found no way to manually draw the contentshape around the content
- move the first item down and use `.offset(y: -300)` on the first item to move it back up: item is clipped outside the `ScrollView`
- use `UIViewRepresentable` with `UIScrollView` and `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(...)` to let all gestures on that area through: I don't know how to implement that (would this be possible?)
- move the first item outside the `ScrollView`: in theory works, but not ideal since the item no longer scrolls and I couldn't get the animations of reordering right
- detach the "upper" view, track the position of the item inside the `ScrollView` and move the upper view manually: probably would lag behind, also not a very elegant solution

Is one of them actually possible? Any other ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 90)
            ForEach((1...15), id: \.self) { _ in
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            }
        }
    }
    .background(.yellow)

    Text("test")
        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
        .background(.red)
}
```

Text is in front of you ScrollView and can't be hit, thus not triggering your ScrollView. From your question, it's hard to guess, what content lies behind your ScrollView and if any further culprits may apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Yes I should have been more specific. There’s a zoomable horizontal and vertical scrollview behind, so magnification, scrolling and tapping should go through. So basically everything